# WebView - The correct way to use credentials

Tags: java, android, webview

I build a password managment application. I store username and passowrd in a database. I want to allow my users to log in to the websites they kept the password to - so I use a webview.
However, when I load the app, the website does not remember my password, like chrome saves your username and passwords and automatically remembers them.
It appers as is the website I try to log in to does not remember my credentials.
I find the right website with a google search using the google search API - it is dynamically found, not a permament one.
**I am looking for a way to autofill the password.**
How can I solve it?

My application's code is like this:

```
package com.example.tehem.webviewapp;

import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.webkit.HttpAuthHandler;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String username = "username" (read from database),
            password = "password"(read from database),
            address = "http://www.ebay.com/"(read from database, found from a search);

    WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);


        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
                                                  HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
                webView.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword(host, realm, username, password);
                handler.proceed(username, password);

            }
            public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                handler.proceed() ;
            }

        });
        webView.loadUrl(address);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

and my XML page is written that way:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="181dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Of course, I allowed an internet premission in AndroidManifest.XML:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: please have a look at my code check if this help

Comment: Thank you Mina Fawzy for spending time to my issue. I can see you faced a problem similar to mine, yet I can't find a soultion in your profile's codes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert with webview widget and how to use it , but as I know you need to keep cookies

According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html) we will use cookie manger to save browser cookies.

> The CookieSyncManager is used to synchronize the browser cookie store
>   between RAM and permanent storage. To get the best performance,
>   browser cookies are saved in RAM. A separate thread saves the cookies
>   between, driven by a timer.

```
onCreate()
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);

onResume()
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();

onPause()
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().stopSync();
```

**UPDATE ANSWER**

as you target Lollipop and `CookieSyncManager` deprecated and according to documentation we no longer need this method we can directly `CookieManager` with method [flush()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#flush())

> To manually force a sync you can use the CookieManager method flush()
>   which is a synchronous replacement for sync()

so result will be

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
      CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
}else {
     // use old methods 
}
```

Comment: Cookie Sync Manager is deprecated as of android Lollipop.
The WebView now automatically syncs cookies as necessary. You no longer need to create or use the CookieSyncManager.
However, I do appreciate you look into other's issues. Thank you

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't rephrase myself clear enoguh at the first time. I have to ask again. 
How can I autofill a password form? I thank you for your time, but I don't think this is the way to do it.